# Statistical analysis approach for seed germination and viability study

Tags: multivariate-analysis, experiment-design, biostatistics, importance

**Background:** I am a stakeholder in a research project involving seed germination and viability tests for a number of shrub species. The ultimate goals of this project are to determine best practices for future storage and use of these species' seed. To investigate this, seeds from a variety of accessions and ages, of numerous species, are subjected to various storage conditions (e.g.: air vs N2, high moisture vs. low moisture, three different storage temperatures, and different lengths of storage time [1-3 years]). Each experiment (e.g.: accession #1 of species A, collected in 2009, stored for 1 year with Air, and at 4 deg C, with low seed moisture), is tested for viability (%) and germination (%). Stratification measures have been applied to break seed dormancy before the experiment begins.

**My problem is the following:** We have received preliminary data (2.5 years' worth of a 3 year study) for almost all species and accessions and tests, and the data are all over the place. A large part of this variability is likely due to the fact that shrub seed is not well-studied, and that the very deep dormancy is not well understood. The researchers have conducted ANOVAs on all of the experiments and their replicates, using initial germination and viability data as part of the comparison. However, this is where their analysis ends. They have identified many experiments that show statistical difference, however there are no further analyses to determine what factors may be causing this significance and having a strong impact on germination or viability.

Because the data are so variable, I am desperately trying to determine a statistical approach to take to try to tease out which factor(s) may be showing the strongest influence on germination or viability. Each experiment combines a number of experimental factors (i.e. seed age, storage time, gas, temperature, moisture), so it would be great if I could understand if one of these factors should be investigated further.

At first, I thought of performing a Principal Components analysis, because I envisioned some sort of ordination that would allow me to visualize how different groups emerge from the data, based on experimental factors. However, I later questioned this idea because all of the factors are controlled, and not measured outcomes of the experiment -- temperature wouldn't affect moisture level or seed age, etc., so I couldn't justify this analysis.

**My question is this:** Is there some way to analyze these data? There are a handful of experimental variables that are controlled, but only one or two response variables (germination or viability over time). I thought that I could think of a strategy to gain more insights into the data, but I am completely lost.

Comment: You are using the term "experiment" differently than I do. Do you mean something like 'individual seed' or 'combination of conditions'? Is your ultimate question 'how do I determine which factors are the most important'?

Comment: Yes, my ultimate question would be "which factors are the most important". Although the study has two broad experiments -- germination and viability tests -- I look at each combination of conditions as a separate, smaller experiment.

Comment: Is germination a subset of viability? Ie, is is possible for viability to be `0` for a particular seed, but germination to be `1`?

Comment: Germination and viability are independent of eachother and are not subsets. Viability pertains to the proper development of the embryo inside the seed, whereas germination involves the emergence of the seedling from the seed. The two are tested in completely different ways, and indicate different aspects of seed health. It is most likely impossible that a seed lot would be 0% viable but still germinate (at any given percentage). I apologize if some of the biology is over your head!

Comment: So you could have 'improper' development of the embryo inside the seed & still have germination?

Comment: So your response variable isn't 0 or 1, then? It is some kind of continuous value w/i the interval b/t 0 & 1?

Comment: Yes. An embryo could develop abnormally and still germinate, although it is more common for abnormal embryos to not germinate at all. For context, germination tests involve moistening a bunch of seeds (usually 100), and then tallying how many emerge every day until all the seedlings emerge or can be accounted for as dead. This results in a germination percentage. Viability tests involve staining the embryo to visualize cellular metabolism, and dissecting out the embryo to analyze it for proper form, shape, etc. Viability tests may explain why a given seed did not germinate.

Comment: Viability will also result in a percentage, ie. how many seeds were viable in a given lot. So yes, germination and viability of seed lots are continuous variables with intervals between 0 and 1 (100%).